# Can I put actions tab on custom new object page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, tasks, vs-code, lightning-components

I've created a Lightning Component to use for the 'new' action of my custom object.  However, I've been asked to put the actions tab, particularly the 'new task' action on the page.

I created the page using VSCode, and I cannot find a way to edit it from the Salesforce UI online to drop that component in.

Is there a way in code (Aura or the Lightning template html) to put this built-in 'new task' action on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-use the activities composer component in this way.

You can create a new page in the lightning app builder (app page, record page or home page) and place your component as well as the activities composer component on it, if that suits your application.

If you want to create a new task at the same time as a new custom object via your custom 'new' button (in what I assume is a modal) you will need to place the fields to capture your task info on your page and save it via your controller.